# Nodemailer: set configuration to send email from custom email

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am using Nodemailer to send emails to my users.

Email used to send emails is 'xyz@toyjunction.online' not gmail.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let sendMail = async (userName, email, password) => {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var smtpConfig = {
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // use SSL
        auth: {
            user: 'xyz@toyjunciton.online',
            pass:'xxxxxx'
        }
    };
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'xyz@toyjunciton.online',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Demo Subject',
        html: `Hi ${userName}, Your new password is ${password}.`
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
        let rtnStatus;
        if (err) {
            reject(false);
        } else {
            resolve(true);
        }
        return rtnStatus;
    });
});
}

module.exports = sendMail;
```

Getting error:

> Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

I have seen a lot of solutions on the internet but not worked for me.

Comment: Do you have a google account for that email address? If not, you need to use google account, not your own email address.

Comment: @JamesZ, Please give me a link of any article that explains it

Comment: @JamesZ, I have created gmail account. Should I use that gmail id to send emails?

Comment: For authentication yes, most likely it doesn't matter what your sender address is